# Changed tub handle and now the sink has low water pressure

Tags: plumbing

Had a leaky faucet so I changed the hot water handle. Prior to install I turned water off to the house and turned sink faucet on to drain pipe. The handle I stall went fine, leak fixed. I turned water back on and shower has full pressure but sink has low pressure.

Comment: your sink valve has a problem, it is not opening full

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include an answerable question? There's an implied problem here you need help with, but you could improve the question by including more detail, photos, and writing the question in an obvious way. Take the [tour] to find out more about Questions and Answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove and clean the faucet aerator. Turning the main off and on can stir stuff up, and that stuff gets caught in the faucet strainers/aerators.